# Community URL Fragment Identifier seems to prevent query execution when setting a default queryString

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, forcenavigatetourl

I have a custom search component that executes a query on keypress - this triggers a [force:navgatetourl](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation) event. My query string contains, a query, and a fragment identifier with custom parameters that will then be used by other components on the search page.

However, my query execution method seems to only work after a second keypress. The initial one results in a URL change which is reflected in the community, however, the page navigation never occurs until a second keypress (enter) is entered. This would seem liek a bug at a first glance, however, if someone notices what I might be doing wrong, feel free to post an answer.

I am properly encoding my url prior to navigating. Here is a minimal reproduceable code sample.

SearchInput.cmp

```
    <aura:attribute name='searchInut' type='String' default='' access='global' />

    <div class="search-container" onkeyup="{!c.handlekeyPress}">
        <lightning:input aura:id="query-box" id="query-box" type="search" name="search" placeholder="additional search terms" value="{!v.searchInut}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

SearchInputController.js

```
    ({
    handlekeyPress  : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        console.log('Keypress--->')
        const theQuery = cmp.find('query-box').get('v.value');
        if(event.which==13){
            console.log('Try to execute on Enter--->')
            helper.executeQuery(cmp, event, theQuery)
        }
    },

})
```

SearchInputHelper.js

```
({
executeQuery : function(cmp, event, theQuery){
    console.log('in helper -- Should trigger query')
    const queryUrl = `/global-search/example-search-term#q=${theQuery}&t=All&sort=relevancy`;
    const theEncodedUrl = encodeURI(queryUrl);
    let urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": theUrl
    });
    urlEvent.fire();  
    console.log('Navigation Event Fired / Should have fired');
    },
})
```

***Last minute update:*** While Creating this post I noticed that if I remove or change my default query (`example-search-term`) to a query dynamically (using string literals or concatenation) the search works normally.

This works:

```
const queryUrl = `/global-search/${theQuery+'#q='+theQuery}&t=All&sort=relevancy`;
```

So - updated question would be why setting a default query seems to prevent the initial navigation event. (looks like a bug)